# SQL JOINs with generic and specific mappings

Tags: mysql, sql, select

From every row from the main table, I want to obtain the *ColWanted* value from the mapping table. For example, for the main table row with id 100 I should obtain 'one', for the id 101 I should obtain 'two', for the 102 'one', 103 'one', etc.

Is it possible?

**Main table**

| PkId | CAT | UP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 1 |
| 101 | 1 | 2 |
| 102 | 2 | 1 |
| 103 | 1 | 3 |

**Mapping table**

| CAT | UP | ColWanted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | one |
| 1 | 2 | two |
| 2 | null | one |

***Update 1***

I tried proposed solutions, like:

```
SELECT m.PkId, m.CAT mCAT, m.UP mUP, p.ColWanted pColWanted, p.CAT pCAT, p.UP pUP
FROm m
LEFT JOIN p ON
    m.CAT = p.CAT AND
    m.Up = COALESCE(p.Up, m.Up)
WHERE m.PkId = 101
```

| PkId | mCAT | mUP | pColWanted | pCAT | pUP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 2 | one | 1 | null |
| 101 | 1 | 2 | two | 1 | 2 |

And it doesn't work as expected. It should return only one row with pColWanted = 'two', but returns two rows. If a specific row (with UP) exist in the mapping table, it shouldn't return the more generic row (without UP).

Comment: "generic" .. do you mean NULL in the Mapping table matches any value?

Comment: @forpas it was a typo, fixed

Comment: Now, *for the 100 'two'* why? Cat = 1 and up = 1 in the Main table do not match with any row in the Mapping table.

Comment: @serg exactly, it could be empty/blank value too

Answer (score 1):

An empty string or NULL in the `MappingTable` is considered matching any value.

```
select m.PkId, p.ColWanted
from MainTable m
left join MappingTable p on (m.CAT = p.CAT or p.CAT is null or p.CAT ='' ) 
       and (m.UP = p.UP or p.UP is null or p.UP ='')
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I explained myself wrong. It should always return only one record, the most "specific", and in this case it returns two. I have updated the question with the result.

Comment: What is the most specific if `(CAT, UP, ColWanted ) = (1, null, Four),(null, 1, Five)`

Comment: You'd better ask another question with a clear statement of  criteria and a wider sample data to cover different cases.

Comment: UP has more priority than CAT. Maybe adding an "ORDER BY up DESC, cat DESC LIMIT 1" at the end could work? Thx

Comment: @Dimas,  as  MySQL considers `NULL` values lower than any non-NULL value it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
SELECT m.PkId, p.ColWanted
FROM MainTable m
JOIN MappingTable p ON m.CAT = p.CAT AND m.UP = COALESCE(p.UP, m.UP)
```

Obvious `m.UP = m.UP` is guaranteed to be true. So when p.UP is NULL, the default is that the match is true.

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I explained myself wrong. It should always return only one record, the most "specific", and in this case it returns two. I have updated the question with the result.